# Get credential provider to invoke AWS Lambda functions when the JAVA application is hosted in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I want to invoke AWS Lambda functions in my java application using aws-java-sdk. It was possible when

1. Access Key and Security Key are given in awsCredentials
2. ARN and payload are given in invokeRequest

as in the following code.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);

AWSLambda awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .build();

InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest()
        .withFunctionName(resourceName)
        .withPayload(payload)
        .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse);

InvokeResult invokeResult = awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);
```

According to AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html, if my java application is hosted in Amazon EC2 instance, it's more convenient to grant secure access to AWS resources from Amazon EC2 instance rather than manually entering access keys. To try that I have implemented the following modified code in my java application hosted in an EC2 instance.

```
InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance();

AWSLambda awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .build();

InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest()
        .withFunctionName(resourceName)
        .withPayload(payload)
        .withInvocationType(InvocationType.RequestResponse);

InvokeResult invokeResult = awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);
```

But it's returning following error

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

I want to know;

1. whether my approach is right to generate credentials
2. if wrong, the right way to do so
3. the reason for the error message

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux?

Comment: Yes. (ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: What happens when you `ssh` into that EC2 instance and run `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`? Is your code running in a docker container in the EC2 instance?

Comment: It returns 


```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>```


No, I'm not using a docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is,

Attach an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) with lambda invoke policy to ec2 instance. Then using Aws sdk without explicitly specifying any ak/sk. The SDK could properly get temporary token from metadata.

Comment: Can you provide example code? Should I create another IAM role with lambda invoke policy though I still have a role with lambda full access? Is metadata updated by creating that role?

Comment: Also, following link helped me to attach an instance profile.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html